# Remove specific kind of text from a string

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

how I can remove price fields from strings? For example I have n items with various of prices (prices frequently change). 
1) VIP Package (80.00 Euro)
2) Standard Package (0.00 Euro)
3) Red Group (25.00 Euro)
...
...
n) Yellow Pack (10.00 Euro)

How can I remove the price fields, and display only Name fields like:
1) VIP Package
2) Standard Package
3) Red Group
...
...
n) Yellow Pack

I know that the 'str_replace' code can help, but I could not configure it. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the price is dynamic you can use 
`explode('(', $string)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace(array('text to replace', 'more text to replace'), '', $the_string);

# str_replace( 'what to search for', 'what to replace with', $variable );
# note that you can use an array or a string for that first argument.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U",
    "<b>example: </b><div align=left>this is a test</div>",
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo $out[0][0] . ", " . $out[0][1] . "\n";
echo $out[1][0] . ", " . $out[1][1] . "\n";
?>
```